# using and method parameter passing

Tags: c#, .net

I am use using to guarantee the resource cleanup. This is fine for the simple block of code.
If I have a method which I need to pass the variable inside the using, can I still guarantee resource clean up?

for example,

```
using ( FileStream fs = -----)
{
      SomeMethod(fs);
}
```

Comment: The short answer is yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  `using(){}` is syntactic sugar, and it will expand your code to this:

```
FileStream fs = -----;
try {
    SomeMethod(fs);
} finally {
    if (fs != null)
        ((IDisposable)fs).Dispose();
}
```

`finally` blocks are guaranteed to execute whether an exception is thrown or not.  The only time they wouldn't be executed is in the case of a severe runtime failure, such as a stack overflow, out of memory exception, or a crash in the runtime itself.

Answer (score 0):

fs's Dispose() method will be invoked at the end of using's code block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be disposed.

See the examples on the [`using Statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) on MSDN - the `Font` is created with passed in parameters.